UIKit view taking equal space in SwiftUI VStack
UIKit view taking equal space in SwiftUI stack
class CustomView: UIView {
    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return label.intrinsicContentSize
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                // Wrapping the UIKit UIView inside a SwiftUI View
                UIKitView(view: CustomView())
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) // Ensure aspect ratio
            }
            
            List(0..<5) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UIKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let view: UIView
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return view
    }
}

want Hello view to height of label (dynamic label size) not the half size.
Make the custom view height dynamic depending on label size.
I tried different ways but they didn't work.

